# Prove the empty set is closed for a metric space (X,d).

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm not sure how to approach the proof for this. I know this statement is vacuously true, because the empty set does not contain any accumulation points. But I'm having a hard time writing a proof for this. I have looked at other answers on here, however we have not learned what a "ball" is in lecture.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Do you understand the notation $(X,d)$ for a metric space that you used in the title?  A "ball" is a set defined in $X$ using the distance function $d$.

Comment: If the empty set doesn't have any accumulation points, then you've just completed the proof. If there are no accumulation points then all accumulation points are in the set. That's it. That *is* the proof. There is absolutely nothing more that needs to be said. You are done. Go to bed.

Comment: ... of course you may have to prove that the empty set has no accumulation points. But that's easy. The empty set has no points so no ball can have any points of the empty set, then no point can be an accumulation point of the empty set. So the empty set has no accumulation points, so all accumulation points of the empty set are in the empty set so the empty set is closed. Go back to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\emptyset$ contains no sequences, it contains all of its accumulation points, which in total there is none. Hence $\emptyset$ is closed.

You can show that $X$ is closed using a similar definition. This time any accumulation is a point in $X$, so $X$ contains all of its accumulation points.

Answer (score 3):

A set is closes iff its complement is open. The complement of the empty set is the whole space which is open in itself.

Comment: We have not learned what an open set is yet. That is in the next lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a topological space. By definition of a topology the set $X$ an open set of $X$. Therefore it's complement (that is $X \backslash X = \emptyset$) is closed.

Comment: We have not learned what an open set is yet. That is in the next lecture.